# mapStateToProps called, but componentDidUpdate didn't called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm fetching data for GameChart from api and change the redux state. Inside GameChart.jsx file I drawing chart when componentDidUpdate called. But redux state change sometimes don't call componentDidUpdate.

---

**Console logs of GameChart.jsx lifecycles**

*`GameChart.jsx` Console logs, when componentDidUpdate didn't called (it happens magically with 50/50 chance...):*

```
Chart mapStateToProps 
Chart componentDidMount
Chart mapStateToProps
```

*`GameChart.jsx` Console logs, when all is OK, and componentDidUpdate called, when redux state changed:*

```
Chart mapStateToProps 
Chart componentDidMount
Chart mapStateToProps 
Chart mapStateToProps 
Chart componentDidUpdate 
Chart mapStateToProps
```

---

***Here is very schematic code:***

*GameChart.jsx*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class GameChart extends Component {
    ...

    componentDidMount() { console.log("Chart componentDidMount") }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log("Chart componentDidUpdate");

        /* When socket.js call initGame, and redux update state, I need to 
           render canvas from this state inside GameChart.jsx */

        ... Drawing chart, using data from this.props.game ...
    }

    render() {
        return (
           <canvas ref={...} ... />
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.log('Chart mapStateToProps');

    return { game: state.game }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GameChart);
```

*gameReducer.js. Action, which `initGame` called*

```
case INIT_GAME:
    return {
        status: action.payload.roll !== null ? "rolling" : "betting",
        ...action.payload
    }
```

*socket.js*

```
/* When websocket connected, it sends current game state to client.
Client need to write this state in redux state and re-render
GameChart.jsx, using this new rewrited by dispatch action state */

socket.onmessage = (msg) => {
    store.dispatch(initGame)(msg);
}
```

---

*I checked redux-dev-tools. Diff tab displays, that game inited successfully and state changed to what websocket gave. I checked out for redux state mutations, there is no state mutations. When refreshing page, sometimes magically componentDidUpdate didn't called, but sometimes it called. It could call arbitrarily with the chance of 50/50.*

Answer (score 3):

*mapStateToProps* connects your redux store to your component's props. The component doesn't rerender when your props are updated(unless the props belong to the state of the parent's state).
*componentDidUpdate* is called when your component's state is updated. A change of props will not affect this.
In short, the props from redux store don't follow the lifecycle hooks of your component.
You will probably need to trigger a rerender your component from where you are calling a dispatch for the redux state.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please, give an example of code?

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` runs on props change as well

Answer (score 2):

`mapStateToProps` is called after `dispatch` has run.
Then Redux does check if result returned is referentially different from previous one. Only if there are differences component is provided with new props. That runs `componentDidUpdate` and `render`.

So you either have referentially same data returned and it's legit reason to miss updating component(and save some time for better performance).

Or your reducer is mutating state(that's no-no for Redux) and you should fix that.

Comment: 1) App connecting to websocket, getting current state of the game:
 init: ({ chat, game }) => {
   store.dispatch(initChat(chat));
  store.dispatch(initGame(game));
 }

And the state isn't the same with initialState when game initialized (I looked at redux-dev-tools, and state changed to different).
2) I don't have state mutations.

Comment: I've run out of new ideas. still I'm sure if there was a bug that preventing Redux from detecting diffs in store data that would be widely known thing.

Comment: In redux-dev-tools Diff tab are couple values. I checked out for mutations again, there is no state mutations. But sometimes magically componentDidUpdate didn't called, when refreshing page again, it could call with the chance 50/50

Comment: try to create minimal reproducible example

Comment: I added the details.

Comment: see nothing suspicious so far. you can replay actions with Redux Dev Tools to see what happens after dispatching.

Comment: The most strange thing: When I did state history rewind inside Redux Dev Tools, game chart draw and componentDidUpdate executed. But before rewind graph didn't draw and componentDidUpdate didn't executed... What a strange things.

Comment: Isn't the point of a reducer to mutate state? Meaning create another immutable state from it.

Comment: @AndyRoid, yes, it's a reducer to produce new store's state. But if you list `a: state.main.a` in `mapStateToProps` it means component will not rerender if your reducer provided new value for `store.sub.b`